# iOS- Unable to get print response in ESC/POS compatible BLE Thermal Printer using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, thermal-printer, escpos

I am trying to print something using [Niyama BT-II Wireless Bluetooth Thermal Printer](https://amzn.eu/d/ih1SmIv) .

I've integrated [ESC/POS Printer Driver for Swift](https://github.com/KevinGong2013/Printer). Tried the example code given in the project. I can successfully connect to the device but when i'm printing something the printer doesn't respond at all.

p.s. tried [caysnprinter](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/caysnprinter/id1107163446) from appstore and i can print fine
.

i want to know how can i build such app using swift that would print on a ESC/POS compatible thermal printer.

Comment: How do you know you have successfully connected to printer? in my case no list showed up